# No GUI after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and I got this:

```
ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS pawan-vostro-3559 tty1

pawan-vostro-3559 login: pawan
password:
last login: sunday Dec 25 17:19:33 IST 2016 on tty1
Welcome to ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS(GNU/Linux 3.19.0-78-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
*Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
```

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: have you tried Ctrl+Alt+F5

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please review Jokerdonio's [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/864423/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In the terminal run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: problem solved just issue is about the os not properly installed thanks kyodake.but what is this:
   /dev/sda2:clean,25344/60760064 files, 7881501/243038200 blocks
it comes during restart or shutdown.

Comment: I had this issue upgrading to 22.04LTS and the above resolved it for me.  Thank you kyodake.